# Android Studio - 2 Toolbars in Navigation Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation

I have created a simple Navigation Drawer Activity and it creates 2 toolbars.
The one on top is not editable and I guess it gets created automatically by the Navigation Drawer somehow since it changes the label on it depending on the fragment.

Example 1: [2 bars visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQZQ8.png)

Example 2: [opened navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VktTA.png)

Example for John: [Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsiGa.png)

How can I remove the not-editable one?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_faq"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_faq" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_statistics"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_statistics" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_dentist"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_dentist" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Beliebiger Titel">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_impressum"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/menu_impressum" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorError"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorError"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="#00000000"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

By removing the toolbar item in app_bar_main.xml I can get rid of one of them but I do not know how / where to edit the one that is left then.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the one in app_bar_main however you want programmatically. I don't understand why you want to create another one. The labels change based on you nav_graph labels if you're using navigation library.

To edit you toolbar you can call `val actionBar = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar` in your fragment and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I dont want to create another one, I have got two and want to get rid of one. If I get rid of it in app_bar_main.xml I do not know how to edit the one that is left then though.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar with NavigationView can be edited.

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"/>
        <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Yes, this does edit the 2nd toolbar; however I want to know how to edit the first one since I want to get rid of the second one later on. The problem is there are 2 toolbars for some reason ..

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how your code looks when running the app ... still 2 bars